# Get "Redirected from" URL

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, redirect, c#-3.0

I have a page A and clicking on a link it gets redirected to page B. From page B is it possible to get the url of Page A. Can anyone explain me how I could get this using C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) property of the request. So on Page B:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string referrer = Request.UrlReferrer;
        // TODO: do something with the referrer
    }
}
```

This being said, the [HTTP Referrer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) can be spoofed so absolutely do not rely on this to implement any kind of security.